# ZF2 doesn't find Controller

Tags: layout, controller, zend-framework2

I have an application with three modules with several controllers in each module. All these controllers work fine. But now, I'm trying to create a new controller in my `Privado` module, in this route /domain/privado/querys/querys.

I have created the controller, her view, and config in *module.config.php*

```
    'privado/querys' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/privado/querys',
                    'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Privado\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Index',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                //'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                                'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id/:system]]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                            'controller'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                            'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                            'id'            => '[0-9]*',
                                            'system'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                                            //'system'  => '[0-9]*'
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
        ), 
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Privado\Controller\Index'              => Controller\IndexController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\Usuario'            => Controller\UsuarioController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\Profile'            => Controller\ProfileController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\Sistemas'           => Controller\SistemasController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\UnidadesServicio'   => Controller\UnidadesServicioController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\Metales'            => Controller\MetalesController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\Pases'              => Controller\PasesController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\Estado'             => Controller\EstadoController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\QuerysController'   => Controller\QuerysController::class,
        'Privado\Controller\TestController'     =>  Controller\TestController::class
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'privado/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/privado/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    /*
     * Con este array de parámetros permitimos enviar datos y no mostrar vista
     */
    'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),          
),
```

And the controller returns me the layout from another module The controller returns me the layout from the `Publico` module. I just understand what I missed.

**Edit 1:**

I've got the wrong layout and this message on the screen:

> A 404 error occurred Page not found.
>
> The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller
>   class.
>
> Controller:
>       Privado\Controller\Querysasdad(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Privado\Controller\Querysasdad)
>
> No Exception available

This is the error that I've got too, If I write a controller which doesn't exists in the url !

I have create another controller in other module following the same steps: create the controller, create the view, config module.config.php and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my terrible error :

In my module.config.php I have in invocables ...

```
'Privado\Controller\QuerysController'   => Controller\QuerysController::class,
'Privado\Controller\TestController'     =>  Controller\TestController::class
```

I fix the problema, remove "Controller" from "Privado\Controller\QuerysController" and "Privado\Controller\TestController"

```
'Privado\Controller\Querys'   => Controller\QuerysController::class,
'Privado\Controller\Test'     =>  Controller\TestController::class
```

Comment: The key of the array does not need to be a path, it just needs to be a unique string to identify the controller. For example it could read: 'QuerysController'   => Controller\QuerysController::class  or even 

'SomethingCrazy' => Controller\QuerysController::class as long as you reference it accordingly on line 7 above